# Do I have to specify type for props both in child and in parent (when passing them down)

Tags: typescript

In a child component I define a prop with a type (in Vue):

```
import { SomeItem } from '~~/types';

interface Props {
  someItems: SomeItem [];                        //<-- prop with type
```

In the parent component, I pass down the data for the `someItems` prop:

```
<MyComponent
    :some-items="myData"
```

But that causes an error:

```
The expected type comes from property 'someItems' which is declared here on type 
'ComponentProps<DefineComponent....
```

I can import the type which seems to fix it:

```
import { SomeItem } from '~~/types';

<MyComponent
     :some-items="myData as SomeItem[]"
```

But do I really have to import the type in the parent each time I want to pass down some data, to set the interface that is defined in the child?
It will require a lot of importing of types.
Is there some other pattern that can be used, or solution for that error?

Comment: You can also use a state management library

Comment: Where are you getting `myData` from?